# Get user's displayname in firebase function once account is created

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app where the user registers for an account with their *email*, *password*, and *displayName*. I want to send a welcome email to the user after they create an account. This is how I create my account and set their display name.

```
// This happens in Android (RegisterActivity.java) where I create user's account
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
                user.updateProfile(new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(name).build());
            }
        });
```

Once the user's account is created, a firebase function is triggered. Below is my code:

```
// This happens in Firebase Cloud Functions (index.js)
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    // send welcome email here
    console.log(user.displayName) // displayName is null here
});
```

I believe that the firebase function gets triggered as soon as the account creation is successful, and I set user's displayname after the account is created and so `displayName` is `null` in the function. What can I do to solve the issue? I don't want to send an email to the user without their name in the email.

Comment: Where are you calling `exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => .. ? `
can you post the class where you are calling this, did you try to call that inside OnSuccessListener, the issue can be they happen on different thread and the sendWelcomeEmail happens before createUserWithPassword has finished.

Comment: @Mina Sorry for the confusion. The first snippet is my Java Android code which creates a user's account. The second snippet is JavaScript code in `index.js` which is deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: displayName is being called before is being set.

The `onCreate` function runs after the front end finishes `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` but before the displayName is set.

Either you run an onCall function after you update the displayName or as suggested on the firebase github thread on this issue you can add a profile parameter to the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` so that we create new accounts with a pre-populated profile.